# How to secure fingerprint data?

Tags: database, security, encryption, privacy, privacy-policy

Our apartment association is planning to implement, biometrics gate passes (fingerprint turnstile) for all residents. But residents are bothered about the data privacy of the fingerprints that are stored in databases. This data resides in association harddisks, which is intended to access by some contract employees working in our apartment.

How I can make sure, data is secure and not misused/sold?

I found something [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7420576), can someone explain how?

Comment: can someone comment why this question is downvoted?

Comment: anyone who downvoted has the eligibility to provide a solution instead of just keeping quiet after downvoting?

Comment: i found something http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7420576 can someone explain how it can be implemented?

Comment: You question is way, way too broad, to the point where noone will know what you're asking. You can possibly get help if you're stuck at a certain point in the implementation and can't figure out a single step of it, but not much more than that. As a side note, I too would be concerned and would never agree to my fingerprints being used for this ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, fingerprint template is nothing but the features of the finger like crosses, deltas, parallel lines, curves and etc. So, using fingerprint template provided by the regular attendance/access control machines, you can not generate image of the real fingerprint. The templates are not unique, every time you register, you will get different string all the time. Also only machines will have the matching algorithm, hence only if the user gives the thumb impression to the  the machine it can validate. So, you will not have the security threads. If see anything as threat, you can specifically say what thread, we can provide you solution.